# How to get the specific value from the data using python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, list

```
data = ['{"osc":{"version":"1.0"}}']
```

or

```
data =  ['{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"testing"}}}}']
```

From the code above, I only get random outputs, but I need to get the last value i.e "1.0" or "testing" and so on.

I always need to get the last value. How can I do it using python?

Comment: the last element of the dictionary. That is "1.0" and "testing"

Comment: @syam.k When you edit, edit everything i.e. code formatting. grammar, and style, if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries have no "last" element. Assuming your dictionary doesn't branch and you want the "deepest" element, this should work:

```
import json
data =  ['{"device":{"network":{"ipv4_dante":{"auto":"testing"}}}}']

obj = json.loads(data[0])
while isinstance(obj, dict):
    obj = obj[list(obj.keys())[0]]
print(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval(data[0])
while(type(x)==dict):
    key = x.keys()[0]
    x = x.get(key)
print(x)
```